# Flask-RESTful: Using GET to download a file with REST

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to write a file sharing application that exposes a REST interface.

The library I am using, Flask-RESTful only supports returning JSON by [default](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#content-negotiation). Obviously attempting to serve binary data over JSON is not a good idea at all.

What is the most "RESTful" way of serving up binary data through a GET method? It appears possible to [extend](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#response-formats) Flask-RESTful to support returning different data representations besides JSON but the documentation is scarce and I'm not sure if it's even the best approach.

Comment: It is really broad question. You extend Flask-RESTful. Nothing stops you from building [Response object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#response-objects) from scratch. If data is static it is probably better to handle that using web-server. Could you add some details.

Answer (score 10):

The approach suggested in the Flask-RESTful documentation is to declare our supported representations on the Api object so that it can support other mediatypes. The mediatype we are looking for is `application/octet-stream`.

First, we need to write a **representation function**:

```py
from flask import Flask, send_file, safe_join
from flask_restful import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@api.representation('application/octet-stream')
def output_file(data, code, headers):
    filepath = safe_join(data["directory"], data["filename"])

    response = send_file(
        filename_or_fp=filepath,
        mimetype="application/octet-stream",
        as_attachment=True,
        attachment_filename=data["filename"]
    )
    return response
```

What this representation function does is to convert the `data, code, headers` our method returns into a `Response` object with mimetype `application/octet-stream`. Here we use `send_file` function to construct this `Response` object.

Our `GET` method can be something like:

```py
from flask_restful import Resource

class GetFile(Resource):
    def get(self, filename):
        return {
            "directory": <Our file directory>,
            "filename": filename
        }
```

And that's all the coding we need. When sending this `GET` request, we need to change the `Accept` mimetype to `Application/octet-stream` so that our API will call the representation function. Otherwise it will return the JSON data as by default.

There's an `xml` example on [github](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/examples/xml_representation.py)

I know this question was asked 7 years ago so it probably doesn't matter any more to @Ayrx. Hope it helps to whoever drops by.

Comment: Thank you for your precise answer with example code. It helped a lot and saved time. I wonder why there is no concrete example in the restful documentation.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you're setting the `Content-Type` header accordingly and respecting the `Accept` header sent by the client, you're free to return any format you want. You can just have a view that returns your binary data with the `application/octet-stream` content type.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trials and experiments, including hours of browsing to make the Response class as Single Responsible down loader

```
class DownloadResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        item_list = dbmodel.query.all()
        item_list = [item.image for item in item_list]

        data = json.dumps({'items':item_list})
        response = make_response(data)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/json'
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=selected_items.json'
        return response
```

Change your filename and content type to support the format you want.